# How to convert JSON object to datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, kendo-ui

I need to show JSON data in Kendo chart.

My code as follows,

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="chart"></div>

$("#chart").kendoChart({
series: [{
    data: [new Date(formatTime(360)).getTime(), // here 360 means seconds
         new Date(formatTime(100)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(125)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(146)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(65)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(185)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(236)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(100)).getTime()],
    color: "Blue",
    name: "Average time",                        
    type: "line"            
},
{
    data: [new Date(formatTime(760)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(100)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(125)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(148)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(65)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(185)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(236)).getTime(),
         new Date(formatTime(100)).getTime()],
    color: "Red",
    name: "Wait time",                        
    type: "bar",            
}       

]
,
valueAxis: {
  labels: {
    template: "#= kendo.format('{0:HH:mm:ss}', new Date(value)) #"
  },
  min: new Date("2018/02/01").getTime(),
  majorUnit: 10 * 60 * 1000 // 20 minutes step
},
tooltip: {
  visible: true,
  template: "#= kendo.format('{0:HH:mm:ss}', new Date(value)) #"
}
});



function formatTime(time) {
var rootDate = new Date(new Date(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).setSeconds(time));
return rootDate;
}
```

here you can see, I set static chart data as `data: [new Date(formatTime(360)).getTime()]` I need to set dynamic JSOn object to chart data from JSON object.

I have the following JSON object.

```
[{
    day: "YYY",
    second: "100",
    second2: "125"
}, {
    day: "XXX",
    second: "145",
    second2: "117"
}, {
    day: "TTT",
    second: "565",
    second2: "340"
}, {
    day: "SSS",
    second: "125",
    second2: "250"
}]
```

I receiving separate JSON key from backend as `second` and `second2`.I need to set those fields to Chart series as `new date` object. how can I do it

Comment: This question has little to do with JSON, unless you have a problem in *parsing* JSON. The object you have is a standard JavaScript array. See the use description of the `json` tag, and maybe review how you use the term "JSON".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `second` should populate the first series (average time) and `second2` the second series (wait time), you could do this:

```
series: [{
    data: arr.map(function (o) {
        return new Date(formatTime(o.second)).getTime();
    }),
    color: "Blue",
    name: "Average time",                        
    type: "line"            
},
{
    data: arr.map(function (o) {
        return new Date(formatTime(o.second2)).getTime();
    }),
    color: "Red",
    name: "Wait time",                        
    type: "bar",            
}]
```

...where `arr` is the array you get from your back-end (after conversion from JSON of course).

Comment: Sir can you please give me an answer without using arrow fucntion. beacuase My browser not support it. and I can'y using ES 5

Answer (score 2):

If you're thinking about getting a new javascript values parsing some string that contains js codes, Just run `eval` function and let it do it's magic. Check this code:

```
let x = 'new Date()';
console.log(eval(x))
```